# Workflow to send reminder mail weekly if task not completed

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

I just got a task to create a workflow to auto send emails weekly to task owners until their task is completed.
The field is called Status. My steps so far:

1. Create a list workflow and use the condition: if value equals value
2. Now I click the first value and use as source my list called Tasks and select the field Status.
3. What should I do with the other 2 dropdown menus called Field and Value??

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely create reminders with a 2013WF.  Should be a conditional loop:

Loop while CurrentItem:Outcome not equals Completed >>>
  Email [USER] >>> 
  then Pause for [Timeframe]

HOWEVER!!!!  This only works for items created manually in the task list.  If you're trying to set a reminder on a task that was created by a WF on a different list (VERY common scenario) a 2013WF will not initiate on that task list.

A 2010 WF will, however.  Unfortunately the Looping capability only exists in 2013.  I've yet to find a graceful way of looping using a 2010 WF.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a SharePoint 2013 workflow you may be able to build a timer on the workflow by utilizing the loop functionality. This is described in another stackexchange post at [Trigger workflow daily](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15962/trigger-workflow-daily). Then you could just do your check weekly and if the task still shows as incomplete fire off the reminder email. You could improve upon it even further by saying if it is REALLY incomplete (like past X time) change the task assigned to the current user's manager.

Answer (score 1):

If the task is created using a designer workflow you can setup a due date for it and send recurring email reminders. Please check if this helps you:
[url][Recurring designer workflow email notifications](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/96871/recurring-designer-workflow-email-notifications)