# Recurring designer workflow email notifications

Tags: workflow

I have a list which has "Due date" and "assigned To" ,"task status"  Fields.and i want to write a designer workflow in such a way that
a. Before the due date, send an alert to the "Assigned To" person every 48 hours unless the task status is changed to "Completed" or "Deferred"
b. After the due date, send an alert to the "Assigned To" person every 8 hours unless the task status is changed to "Completed" or "Deferred"

I know we can not use whlie loop in designer workflow.Could you please suggest me how can we acheive this with if-else loops.

Answer (score 5):

Is this in SharePoint 2013? If yes, SharePoint Designer 2013 Create Task action should let you choose if you want to send out recurring reminder and options for that.

If you add a new "Assign a task" action in SPD, if you click on "this user" you can set up Due Date for created task as well as Overdue Emails:

[image: Task settings]

For SharePoint Designer 2010, you can follow these steps to create "pseudo" reminder:

http://kmlsp.wordpress.com/2013/03/06/more-on-calendar-reminder-4-steps-to-create-reminder-workflow-in-sharepoint-calendar/

Comment: Please add more details regarding how to do what you propose (like step by step instructions). Your answer is not as helpful as it could be right now

Comment: Done with changes, hopefully this is more... useful :)

Comment: Another question - is it SharePoint Designer workflow or custom Visual Studio developed one?

Comment: Edited my answer to provide you with a link to SharePoint Designer 2010 solution that should give you similar result (albeit not so out of the box like 2013 does :)).

Comment: yeah..i got how to create a sharepoint list workflow.
Do you have any logic which should send email for every 48 hrs or 8hrs continuosly.

Comment: how can we acheive with IF-else loop?

Comment: Here's another blog post that shows you how to use If-else conditional to create a recurring reminder every 7 days. This combined with other blog post should give you everything you need: http://sharepoint713.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/sharepoint-designer-workflow-to-send.html

Comment: I have followed these steps, and in fact had already done so before reading this question/answer ... still the emails do not send. The only difference must be important: I do not have "Wait for task completion" checked. My assumption is that the overdue emails are only sent if the workflow is set to wait for task completion. This should be documented somewhere but i sure can't find it ...