# Terminate Workflow on Due date

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I would like to terminate a workflow on due date. Is it possible to do so using SharePoint 2010 workflows?
I was thinking of creating two parallel tasks and wait for the due date and terminate workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Here I assume that you are creating a designer workflow.

you can compare the current date with the due-date of the task and if it matches then you can terminate the workflow using the workflow action in sharepoint designer.

Comment: Yes. Do I need to create a timer for this?

Comment: no you dont need to create a timer, 

your workflow will run everyday ?

Comment: Not exactly.

I have a workflow which do some tasks and creates an approval workflows. However, if the user does not approve or reject within the due date. the workflow is automatically approved.

Comment: you can try to schedule the workflow as mentioned in [this question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15962/trigger-workflow-daily), and then check for the duedate comparison result