# Workflow to update all List Items

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, timer-jobs, updatelistitems

I have written a workflow many times that run for a single list item whenever it gets created/updated.

I want to create a workflow to update all the existing list items.

How can this be done?

An idea which I have in my mind is-

1. Create a new temporary list. This be used only to run the workflow.
2. Workflow Functionality-

   a. I will provide static `ID` in a variable. This `ID` will be the max ID in the List I want to update.

   b. Will run loop from 1 to max ID.

   c. Will update the Items for every row

Answer (score 1):

Workflow is associated to a list item. Basically which gets executed when related item get added or updated.

For your requirement you need to loop through each item and do the update. Which is tricky to implement via SPD workflows.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please have a look

Answer (score 1):

you need make SPD Workflow run at particular schedule to perform your updates of list item. May be you can run SPD workflow daily to perform your task.

For your reference you can look into following Q&A from Stack Exchange.

[Trigger workflow daily](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15962/trigger-workflow-daily)

[Schedule a workflow to run everyday](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138098/schedule-a-workflow-to-run-everyday)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to make an update to existing items (one time activity).
You can create powershell script/ console application . Loop through the list item and programmatically invoke the workflow on the list item.