# Email a specific date range of a list in issue tracking with SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

Is there's a way that i can send all the list on issue tracking list through Email?

For Example:

[image]

I just want this to send through email using SharePoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how do you want them to be sent.

The simplest way is to create a SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow (set it to run each time a new item is added to the list) which send email each time an issue is created.

If you want to send all of them there are some approaches though:

1. Write a custom timer job which will run at your desired schedule. Of course inside the timer job, you could write code to send issues from that list.
2. Setup a SharePoint Designer Workflow to run on schedule. You could refer to this [question's](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15962/trigger-workflow-daily) first answer about how to set it up. 
   Inside the workflow, create a loop activity to loop through list items. This [article](http://usamawahabkhan.blogspot.co.id/2012/10/create-sharepoint-2013-workflow-loop-by.html?goback=.gde_3724282_member_176524340) provides a good information about how to use loop activities (assuming you are also using SharePoint 2013 workflow).